# Adding links for each genre through loops in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, loops, href

I have been trying to figure out **d)** and would really appreciate any help!

Below is the assignment. I have completed everything except for the last

"Using the starter code available in course content, add the following array:

```
var genres = ["Fiction", "Comedy", "Drama", "Horror", "Non-fiction", "Romance", "Satire"];
```

**a)** Create a  element first and append to the body. Loop through the array, adding "li" elements to the "ul", with the each of the array items as the "li" content.

**b)** Instead of creating a list, make a table and put each array item in a "td" (table column)

**c)** Instead of columns, create table rows.

**d)** Outside of the loop used above, turn each word into a link, and link to a Wikipedia page for that word (target="_blank"). Note how Wikipedia structures their URL on the site."**

How would this be done?

Comment: What work have you done so far?  SO is not a homework service.

Comment: It would be nice if you provide us a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) .. This will help us to help you solve your query..

Comment: I know its not a hw service but I am seriously struggling. I didn't ask for the whole answer but just an example of how the last part could be done.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/41xdpuek/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over the array - create a str with each link and then pass it into the html to create a list of the wiki links. The has the added benefit of amending the DOM only once.

Note the structure of the href for the wikipeadia page is "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiction" so thats all you have to build in the string and substitute each item of the array at the end.

```js
var str='';

var genres = ["Fiction", "Comedy", "Drama", "Horror", "Non-fiction", "Romance", "Satire"];

genres.forEach(function(genre) {
 str += '<li><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/'+genre+'">'+ genre + '</a></li>';
})

document.getElementById('wikiLinks').innerHTML = str;
```

```html
<ul id = 'wikiLinks'></ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining this.

Comment: No problems - happy to help. Incidentally if you want the jQuery equivalent of the above - it would be $('#wikiLinks').html(str); and make sure that you wrap it in a document.ready wrapper. Happy coding.